# How should i calculate that in Arduino

Tags: arduino

If the voltage across a 16 mF capacitor is 7 volts at t=0, find the voltage across the capacitor after 0.2 seconds of discharging through a 120 Ω resistor.

Comment: Homework ? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions
What have you already tried ? searched for ? found ? At which step exactly do you need help? The question better fits http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Substitute your values into the capacitor discharge equation:

```
Vc = Vi * exp(-t/RC)

Vc = voltage across the capacitor at time 't'
Vi = Voltage across capacitor at t = 0
```